# Minimizing a specific cost function with respect to a constraint

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

I'm looking for a closed form solution to determine $x_i$ $\forall i = 1,2,..N$, where we have a constraint $B$:

> $$B = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N D_i*x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N D_i}$$, where $0 \le B \le 1$ and $D$ is a constant per $i$.

and the cost function is something simple and needs to be minimized with respect to $x_i$:

> $$min \space  \sum_{i=1}^Nx_i*y_i $$ , where $y_i$ is a constant per $i$.

I found a simple solution in the form of:

> $$ x_i = 1-(1-B)*(\frac{y_i*\sum_{i=1}^n D_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n D_i*y_i})$$

Is this correct? Does someone finds a different answer? Love to hear your thoughts on this problem.

Comment: ?? Why would it not be possible ?@UnbelieveTable

Comment: okay. Edited a bit. Saw I forgot a summation :o. $y$ is different per $i$, but when optimizing per $i$, $y$ remains a constant.

Comment: The summation of $x_i*y_i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the constraints can also be written as
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^N D_ix_i &\geq 0 \\
\sum_{i=1}^N D_ix_i &\leq \sum_{i=1}^N D_i 
\end{align*}
$$
where $D_i$ is constant and $\sum_{i=1}^N D_i $ is also a constant.
To illustrate this question, we may first consider it in two dimensions (the $x_1$-$x_2$ plane). Then the question is
$$\begin{align*}
&\text{min} &&y_1x_1+y_2x_2 \\
&\text{s.t.} &&D_1x_1+D_2x_2 \geq 0 \\
&&&D_1x_1+D_2x_2 \leq D_1+D_2 \\
\end{align*}$$
Now, the feasible region is simply the region bounded by a line $l_1$ (from the first constraint) through the origin $(0,0)$ and a line $l_2$ (from the second constraint) which is parallel to $l_1$. Since $D_1+D_2$ is nonzero, these two lines are not identical, and the feasible region is unbounded from negative infinity to positive infinity. Assume the objective value is 
$$
k = y_1x_1+y_2x_2
$$
which is any line in the coordinate. The intersection of this line with the feasible is also unbounded from negative infinity to positive infinity.

The above conclusion can also be deduced to $N$ dimensional, and the OP is unbounded.

Comment: But the constraint is that B is a fixed number between Zero and 1, Lets say 0.95 so the constraint is that the Sum of D times $x_i$ divided by the Total Sum of D is equal to 0.95

Comment: If that is what you mean, then the feasible region is just the line $$\sum_{i=1}^ND_ix_i = 0.95\sum_{i=1}^ND_i=c$$ for some constant $c$ and it is also unbounded from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks but like the question stated: im looking for a closed form formula and not the feasible region or how to solve it as a linear program...any suggestions?

Comment: @Steven31415 
What I stated is that this linear program is unbounded, meaning that you can always choose a solution $x_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^N y_ix_i$ is smaller, all the way to the negative inifinity. Namely, there is no optimal solution.

Comment: @Steven31415 If you restrict $x_i$ to be non-negative, it is solvable. For the OP, that is a no.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I forgot to state that $x_i$ is also constraint the same way as $B$. So I'll put a new question up for that. You can see the problem as N-items that need a number between 0 and 1 ($x_i$) and this $x_i$ incurs a cost $y_i$. But in the end, multiplying each $x_i$ with $D_i$ has to be equal to $B$.

Comment: here is the new question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459624/finding-a-closed-form-formula-for-an-objective-cost-function-with-a-equality-con